# "Proto prime" subsequences

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ be viewed as a sequence. We say $S^\prime \subset S$ is a *proto-prime* subsequence if the elements of $S^\prime$ are increasing, pairwise co-prime, and $S^\prime$ is infinite.

The motivation for this definition is the following result: if $\mathbb{N}$ contains a proto-prime subsequence, then there are infinitely many prime numbers.

Proof of the claim: let $S = \{s_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a proto-prime subsequence of $\mathbb{N}$. Let $P = \{p_1, \cdots, p_k\}$ be a finite set of primes. By the definition of proto-primitivity, each element of $P$ can divide at most one element of $S$, and since $|S| = \infty$, it follows from the fundamental theorem of arithmetic that there exists a prime outside of $P$ which divides some element of $S$, and this proves the infinitude of primes.

Indeed, this is really the spirit of Euclid's proof of the infinitude of primes: he really showed that starting from any finite set of primes, one can produce a proto-prime subsequence of the natural numbers.

My questions are:

1. what are some necessary and sufficient conditions for a subsequence $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ to have a proto-prime subsequence?
2. Are there any sequences where we expect to contain infinitely many primes, for which we can find a proto-prime subsequence whose density is of the same order of magnitude as we expect the subsequence of primes to have?

Here is a cute example: consider the sequence $S = \{2^n - 3\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Then $S$ contains a proto-prime subsequence. Indeed, starting from a finite subset $\{a_1, \cdots, a_k\}$ of $S$ which are pairwise co-prime, one can consider the number $N = a_1 \cdots a_k$. Then by the pigeonhole principle, among $1, 2, \cdots, 2^N$ there exist two indices $i < j$ such that $2^j \equiv 2^i \pmod{N}$. Since $N$ is clearly odd it follows that $N | 2^{j - i} - 1$. Put $\ell = j - i$. Then $4N+1 = 2^{\ell + 2} - 3$, and it is obvious that $\gcd(N, 4N+1) = 1$. Hence we can add $a_{k+1} = 2^{\ell + 2} - 3$ to the list, and use this to construct a proto-prime subsequence of $S$. This particular question appeared on the 1971 IMO.

Comment: Note that your protoprime sequence trick has been used in other proofs that there are infinitely many primes also. The classic example is using Fermat numbers, $2^{2^n}+1 $.

Comment: Also, one easy set of sequences containing protoprime subsequences are made by the following: Fix a non-constant polynomial P(x) with integer coefficients  and constant term $\pm 1$, and positive lead coefficient Then. {P(n)>0} contains a protoprime subsequence. The proof is essentially the same as Euclid's argument.

Comment: On a side note, *protoprime* is a curious mixture of the Greek name *πρῶτος*  and of its exact Latin correspondent, *primus* --both are superlative forms of prepositions, both mean "first" and, in mathematics, "prime" (number)

Comment: @Stanley Yao Xiao: I have two  questions: Is it necessary to mention both $S^{\prime}$ and $S$ in your definition of "proto-prime subsequence"? Wouldn't it suffice to declare $\{s_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ as a proto-prime sequence of natural numbers when the following three requirements are met: a) all of the terms of the sequence are natural numbers, b) for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $s_{n}<s_{n+1}$, and c) $\mathrm{gcd}(s_{m}, s_{n})=1$ for any $(m,n) \in (\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}) \setminus \{(m,m) \colon m \in \mathbb{N}\}$?

Comment: Further, could you give elaborate a bit on your second question? There are several notions of "density"... Which is the one one that you have in mind there?

Comment: @JoséHdz.Stgo. yes, it is necessary to have both $S, S^\prime$ in the definition, because I want to consider proto-prime subsequences of arbitrary sequences of natural numbers, not just the natural numbers themselves. For example the sequence $\{n^2 + 1\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not proto-prime but contains a proto-prime subsequence. As for density, it is the usual asymptotic density, ideally given in terms of a relatively simple function.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a sequence which has NOT a protoprime subsequence. All I can think is something like $a_n=p_1^{b_1(n)}\cdots p_k^{b_k(n)}$ for some fixed primes $p_1, \ldots ,p_k$.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas It doesn't need to be nearly that restricted; consider $a_n = 2b_n$ for any natural sequence $b_n,$ for example. Or $a_n = b_nc_n$ where $c_n$ is $\{p_1,\ldots,p_k\}$-smooth to adapt your example.

Comment: @Charles Ok, all the primes need not to be fixed, but nevertheless we have to keep some fixed prime divisors and add some more in the process.